# How to add a timeout when reading from `stdin`

Tags: c, if-statement

I need to check if the user took more than 3000ms to give input on `stdin`.

Is there a way to add a timeout when waiting for user input? Something like

```
if (timeout) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

Comment: "Return value: Zero if the requested time has elapsed, or the number of seconds left to sleep, if the call was interrupted by a signal handler." https://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep

Comment: "does not work" is not a proper problem description. Elaborate. And provide a [mcve]

Comment: can you give me a example? i understand but no have minimal ideia to make this program.

Comment: my question is small and objective, so I did not even put in big code.

Comment: `sleep()` accepts the number of *seconds*, not *milliseconds*.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Doing `if(sleep(3)) printf("yes"); else printf("no")` makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: whatever , just that I can not use it as a condition.

Comment: this code is an example if I want something to happen if the user does not type in a good time. understand?

Comment: Now I can understand your question. You want a *timeout* on a user typing. Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322143/add-a-timeout-for-getchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following program will read from `stdin` with a timeout, which is what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

#define LEN 100

int main() {
    struct timeval timeout = {3, 0};
    fd_set fds;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds);
    printf("Hi. What is your name?\n");
    int ret = select(1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    if (ret == -1) {
        printf("Oops! Something wrong happened...\n");
    } else if (ret == 0) {
        printf("Doesn't matter. You're too slow!\n");
    } else {
        char name[LEN];
        fgets(name, LEN, stdin);
        printf("Nice to meet you, %s\n", name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```